# How can i click an <a> button inside 2 divs in selenium python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, button

I'm trying to make selenium click `Button1` but for some reasons, I get the following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
> Message: Unable to
> locate element: Button1

I believe the error is happening because it is inside a `div`/`ul`/`li` tag but I can't either figure out how to do it, I'm stuck.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="contentArea">
<div class="pageNavigation" id="pageNavigation">
    <ul>
        <li>

            <a href="#">Button1</a>

        </li>
        <li class="last">       

            <a href="#">Button2</a> 
                                            
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**Python Code:**

```
from selenium import *

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(1366, 768, driver.window_handles[0])
driver.get("https://localhost/mypage/index.php")
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Button1').click()
```

**Edit:** I found out that the html is generated through javascript. my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try the following methods**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Button1']").click()
```

**Or try like you said, to locate the element inside `div/ul/li`**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pageNavigation']/ul[1]/li[1]/a[1]").click()
```

**And if that doesn't work for some reason, try with `ActionChains`**

> *For that, you need to import the module*

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**Then use it to click on the element,

this has been a life savior for me in some situations**

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Button1']")
action.click(on_element=element).perform()
```

Comment: Your response is great! But i think i found out why it isnt working, because the html is generated through javascript.

Comment: If that's the case you can try - driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('pageNavigation')[0].click()")

Comment: I get  the following error sadly `selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined` Anyway thanks for the help, im gonna figure it out somehow! :)